# Can I split a string into a nested list where the outer list contains a list for each sentence and the inner list contains the words of each sentence?

Tags: python, string, list, split

So I have the following string:

```
string1 = " This is random text! I am trying to split this text into a nested list. Where each sentence is its own list and the values of that list contain the words and punctuation of that sentence. Is this possible? If not, why not? "
```

I need to split this into a nested list like the one below.

```
nested_list = [["This", "is", "random", "text", "!"] ["I", "am", "trying", "to", "split", "this", "text", "into", "a", "nested", "list", "."], ["Where", "each", "sentence", "is", "its", "own", "list", "and", "the", "values", "of", "that", "list", "contain", "the", "words", "and", "punctuation", "of", "that", "sentence", "."], ["Is", "this", "possible", "?"], ["If", "not", ",", "why", "not", "?"]]
```

I know that string.split() method can take parameters, but I can't figure out to break up the paragraph at all periods, question marks and exclamation marks. Because from my understanding the string.split() only takes the one parameter.

Comment: Did you make any attempt? Could you post the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use python built-in:

```
import re
re.split(r'[!?.|,|\*|\n]',string1)
```